# Can two different controllers access a single view in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two different controllers and I want both of them to use a Common View.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes**.Mention the view full path in the `View` method.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult ShowUser()
   {
     return View();
   }
}
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult ShowAccount()
   {
     return View("~/Views/User/ShowUser.cshtml");
   }
}
```

If the name of your Views are same in both the controllers, You can keep the Common view under the `Views/Shared` directory and simply call the View method without any parameter. The View name should be same as the `Action` method name.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult ShowUser()
   {
     return View();
   }
}
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult ShowUser()
   {
     return View();
   }
}
```

Assuming you have a View called `ShowUser.cshtml` under `Views/Shared` folder.